# Can anybody identify this IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

It's part of a power supply for an LED light that's supposed to look like a neon light.
Input: 120VAC, 0.30A
Output: 4.5VDC, 1.5A

The light is broken and is flashing at about a rate of 1Hz and I'm trying to fix it.

edit for clarity: I don't think its this IC. I'm just trying to sketch out the circuit completely as a learning exercise.

[image]

Comment: It's probably flashing because there's a short and the power supply is cycling.  When they detect an over-current condition, it'll shut down, reset and try again.   Usually indefinitely.   Look for something more obvious than guessing at bad IC's.   ie.. don't assume it's your power supply, it might be the LED light it's trying to drive that's bad.  if its the supply, check the EL capacitors for signs of leaking or bulging.  That'd be my first guess, not a bad IC.     i.e.   http://www.robotroom.com/Parts/Samsung-monitor-capacitors/Bad-electrolytic-capacitors-with-residue-buldging-and-lift.jpg

Comment: What makes you believe the IC is faulty?

Comment: @winny I don't think anyone claimed the chip being faulty. Identifying the chip would mean possibility of finding a datasheet and gaining better understanding of the circuitry to find the problem.

Comment: I've run into this several times. I am assuming that all of the LEDs are in series. If so, try shorting out 1 or 2 (or even more) LEDs and see what happens. Chances are that the flashing will stop.

Comment: @Justme That could be the case, yes.

Comment: @winny I don't think its this IC. I'm just trying to sketch out the circuit completely as a learning exercise.

Comment: If you don't have any luck finding data for the chip, why not try asking Clive Mitchell.  www.bigclive.com  He does tear-downs of many LED lights and seems to have  real knack for finding data sheets.

Comment: May I just say I really appreciate that the OP is putting in effort to trace out the circuit and learn how it works rather than simply saying "it's broken, how do I fix it?"

Comment: Add another photo for the whole circuit, it will help people at least understand its role and make better assumptions and guesses

Comment: @khelms Good. Please put that in your question. There is at least one question per week “Thing X broke and I found component Y inside it and I want to replace it” when it’s obviously not Y but Z that is broken.

Comment: It's not a great pic, is this a SOT323 or something larger?

Comment: I noticed this:
https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/help-identifying-a-6-pin-smd-ic-in-a-power-supply/ If the positive rail and ground are known (you can ohm it out) now you are down to 4 functional pins. Are any of the remaining 4 pins tied to discretes that could: set a switcher frequency or drive transistors or drive a FET or get feedback through a resistor divider? Pleas post the schematic and BOM you have so far. Fly back and many other circuits are recognizable by their topology. Earlier decades of electronics were full of rebranded or knockoff chips so you may never know the OEM.